# Is there a way to disable all next.js api routes in production environment?

Tags: next.js

During the developing phase, API routes are good for me with Mock data.

While in the Production environment, I have my own backend service.

Is there a way to disable all the API routes?

Comment: You could setup a [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) rule in production only to proxy your `/api/*` requests to your backend API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @juliomalves' suggestion, I found it can add redirect rules in `next.config.js` to disable (redirect to 404) all the `/api/*` requests

```
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      return [
        {
          source: "/api/:slug*",
          destination: '/404',
          permanent: true,
        }
      ];
    } else {
      return []
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this snippet? Can you mention a file name?

Comment: next.config.js This file!